# How to perform the security testing using selenium?

Tags: security, selenium, testing, zap

I already develop a Selenium code to perform the web application testing. But i need to perform the security testing for the same application. So Please suggest me how to perform the security testing with selenium code .

Please help to integrate the selenium with ZAP.

Comment: Selenium can not be used for Security testing. You would need to look for some other tools which can perform security testing.

Comment: Hi @Anish pillai we can connect the Selenium with ZAP. ZAP will do the security testing and Selenium will perform the functional testing. But i need to know how to achieve that.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Sorry I have no idea about ZAP. So won't be able to give any info on it.

Comment: Isnt ZAP a proxy? Have you tried using desiredcapabilities or chromeoptions to setup the proxy settings for the browser?

Comment: @Grasshopper I am not tried any thing on that. will you help me to do that.

Comment: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/03/how-to-set-proxy-settings-in-selenium.html . This should help.

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper will you able to help me to perform the security testing using selenium

Comment: Never done security testing... Will not be able to provide much help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proxy your Selenium tests through ZAP and then use ZAP to test your app.
Exploring apps effectively is always a challenge for automated scanners, but a good set of Selenium tests are a great way to teach a scanner like ZAP about how your app works. You can either not bother using the ZAP Spiders or just use them to catch areas of you app that dont have enough tests. By proxying your tests via ZAP you will automatically get passive scanning, and once they have finnished you can use active scanning to run the more agressive attacks.
ZAP has a very powerful API so can be completely automated for this sort of testing.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Bennetts . Will you please provide me any same code or any reference sites which will helpful for me to active this.

Comment: Is python ok for driving the ZAP API? If so have a look at https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python/blob/master/src/examples/basic-spider-scan.py

If not, which language would you rather use?

Comment: Thanks @Simon Bennetts. I am using Selenium code with JAVA.

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestions @Simon Bennetts. Surly it will help for me.